# Rails ActiveRecord: How to select the top X records for each day, for multiple days in a single query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The model is Posts, and each post has upvotes:integer
Hundreds of posts are created each day, and I want to return a the top 10 upvoted posts from each day with a single query.

ordered chronologically

I want to return the results for the past year, and show the top 10 posts from each day in the same query.

the expected result should be:

top 10 posts from today, top 10 posts from yesterday ... top 10 posts from the beginning.

is there any way to do this query without doing a loop and individual query for each day?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Post.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today).order("upvotes DESC").limit(10)
```

Here `Date.today` take today's date, you can pass any date to get top 10 for that particular day.

Comment: this only works for 1 day, I updated the description

Answer (score 0):

The more precise query would be

```
Post.where("created_at = ?", Date.today.beginning_of_day)
    .order("upvotes DESC").limit(10)
```

Comment: this only works for 1 day, I updated the description

Answer (score 0):

Well any of the above solutions will work perfectly well if you have `upvotes` column in your `posts` table, however, if you have it in a separate table, which you ideally should, you would need something like below for the same:

```
query = <<-QUERY
  SELECT posts.*,
  Count(upvotes.*) AS upvotes_count
  FROM   posts
  LEFT JOIN upvotes
        ON upvotes.post_id = posts.id
  WHERE  Date(posts.created_at) = #{Date.today}
  GROUP  BY posts.id
  ORDER  BY upvotes_count DESC
QUERY

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).entries
```

This is with raw sql though. You can convert it to ActiveRecord if you need.